# How get the most frequent value in an ARRAY in sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I´m a newbie in SQL.

I have built an array where I have been storing the values ​​that I have been collecting in a loop and dividing them by other value.

The array has the correct values.

Now I would need to get the most repeated value in this array.

Is this possible with SQL? 
My environment is Oracle 11.

This is the array:

```
type array_type is varray(100) of NUMBER(10);
loop_results array_type := array_type();
```

The values:

```
 1: 906450
 2: 906450
 3: 306449
 4: 906446
 5: 306450
 6: 906447
 7: 306449
 8: 306448
 9: 306448
10: 306450
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: FYI: The code you posted is actually PL/SQL which is a proprietary Oracle extension to SQL.

Comment: It's quite easy if you make array_type to be a `table of number(10)` instead of a `varray(100) of number(10)`. Then you can `select * from table(loop_results)`.

Comment: In T-SQL (MS SQL SERVER) we do it like this: DECLARE  `@array TABLE(Nums INT)
INSERT INTO `@array VALUES ('906450'),('906450'),('306449'),('906446'),('306450')
 ,('906447'),('306449'),('306448'),('306448'),('306450'),('306450')

SELECT Nums, COUNT(Nums) AS [Count] FROM `@array
GROUP BY Nums
ORDER BY [Count] DESC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in SQL if the type is declared in the SQL scope:

```sql
CREATE TYPE array_type is varray(100) of NUMBER(10);
```

Then (Oracle 12+ solution)

```sql
SELECT COLUMN_VALUE,
       COUNT(*)
FROM   TABLE(
         array_type(
           906450,
           906450,
           306449,
           906446,
           306450,
           906447,
           306449,
           306448,
           306448,
           306450
         )
       )
GROUP BY COLUMN_VALUE
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW WITH TIES;
```

or (for earlier versions, you can use analytic functions):

```sql
SELECT value,
       cnt
FROM   (
  SELECT COLUMN_VALUE AS value,
         COUNT(*) As cnt,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC ) AS rnk
  FROM   TABLE(
           array_type(
             906450,
             906450,
             306449,
             906446,
             306450,
             906447,
             306449,
             306448,
             306448,
             306450
           )
         )
  GROUP BY COLUMN_VALUE
)
WHERE  rnk = 1;
```

Outputs all the values that are tied for the highest frequency:

> ```
> COLUMN_VALUE | COUNT(*)
> -----------: | -------:
>       306449 |        2
>       906450 |        2
>       306450 |        2
>       306448 |        2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [Oracle 18](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fd3763b7d8e462f8961127b76c1d9913) or [Oracle 11](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e87259f019baed76f75165883fd6a56e)*

Comment: Thank you very much I´m trying it but with Oracle 11 is not running and with Oracle 18 yes. I´m testing in db<> fiddle and I have the same error: PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended. My environment is Oracle 11

Comment: @JohnGilbert Oracle 11 does not support the row limiting (`FETCH FIRST ...`) syntax as that was introduced in Oracle 12c. You can use analytic functions instead [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e87259f019baed76f75165883fd6a56e). Also, if you've got a test that is giving an error then it is more constructive to give us a link to the db<>fiddle so we can see what you've done rather than just saying there's an error without any accompanying code.

Comment: Sorry, here is the link https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=fd3763b7d8e462f8961127b76c1d9913

Answer (score 1):

First of all arrays are a part of pl/sql. Likewise try the below. The below would be somewhat easy using a temporary table.

```
  Create table sample(value1 
   number(10));
  Declare
  type array_type is varray(100) of 
  NUMBER(10);
  loop_results array_type := array_type();
   Max varchar2(20);

    begin
     for i in 1..loop_results.length
     loop
     Insert into sample values
     (loop_results(i)) ;

     End loop
     Select value1 into max from(Select 
      Value1, 
      count(*) 
       from sample order by count(*) desc
      Group by value1) where rownum=1;

   dbms_output.put_line(max) ;

     End
```

Comment: Collections and `VARRAY`s are not solely available in PL/SQL; they can be declared in the SQL scope too. Associative Arrays are solely a PL/SQL data type.